# How to create web app using public API?

Tags: jquery, json, api, web-applications, getjson

I'm interested in creating a web app that uses data provided via the DSIRE public API - http://programs.dsireusa.org/api/v1/getprograms/json (Note: these are large queries that return thousands of results).

The web app would be a simple input field that asks for a Zip Code and then the results should be retrieved and filtered based on the input value. The API call is from the [DSIRE database](http://www.dsireusa.org/resources/data-and-tools/) and is offered in both XML and JSON format. I would like to work with the JSON format because I initially thought it would be best to use the `$.getJSON` function in jQuery.

I read a few tutorials on how to use the `$.getJSON` function but I have a couple questions about using the supplied JSON data:

1. It looks as if the API does NOT allow for URL parameters which I assume would allow me to filter the results (i.e ../getprograms/json?zipcode=value)
2. The JSON data file is so large and takes a long time to load. I assume I would have to store that data somehow before querying to reduce load times.

I would like to know how to get started creating such a web app. What frameworks and/or libraries would be best to get started?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

There are a variety of frameworks for creating the REST API that you desire. Wikipedia lists them by programming language and there are variety of different frameworks you can research about. I've worked with Django, Flask, and Laravel, and there are multiple tutorials on creating a web app on these three alone. Here are some good starter links:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-the-django-rest-framework--cms-19786

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

and there are plenty of others by googling "REST API tutorial" or "Framework REST API". Also, Ruby on Rails is a great programming language (from what I've researched) for creating a web app you've described.

Comment: Here are the list of frameworks from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_frameworks#Python

Comment: What is the reasoning behind creating the REST API, or why is that necessary for my purposes? I ask this because they already offer an "API".

Comment: @katart you definitely do not have to create a REST API, but it would make things easier on yourself because there are things that the REST API could do with ease (filtering, querying, etc.). These web frameworks wrap all that up in a sequence that makes sense. It's just good practice. But it sounds like you simply want to work with the data from the JSON and display that. These frameworks are still good tools for accomplishing that goal, and you definitely don't have to make a REST framework. In fact, you could probably get by doing this with html, css, and JS.

Comment: I'll research creating a REST API in PHP since that's the language I'm most familiar with. I assume creating a REST API from the supplied data helps "store" the data for quick query results. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @katart yes, you can write code using a web framework that allows you to order by different attributes. For instance, if you wanted to, you could write code that returned the list of results in the ascending order of zipcodes or income or whatever parameter you set.